# Why does the Python script to send data to Slack web hook not work when variable is pulled from a line?

Tags: python-2.7, io, with-statement, slack-api

Language:  Python 2.7

Hello all.  I found a really helpful script here: [Python to Slack Web Hook](https://gist.github.com/devStepsize/b1b795309a217d24566dcc0ad136f784)

that shows how to send messages to a Slack web hook.

```
import json
import requests

# Set the webhook_url to the one provided by Slack when you create the webhook at https://my.slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook/
webhook_url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
slack_data = {"text": "<https://alert-system.com/alerts/1234|Click here> for details!"}

response = requests.post(
    webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_data),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
if response.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError(
        'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s'
        % (response.status_code, response.text)
    )
```

It works flawlessly when I run .py file.

Now, I have a file that has many lines of messages that I want to send to Slack.  I have it formatted correctly already in the file, no spaces etc..  It's just a matter of grabbing it and passing it so slack_data = line1  etc..

So, I modify the file with something like this:

```
with open('export.txt', 'r') as e:
    for line in e:

        slack_data = line
```

Now if I do a `print slack_data` right after that, the information returns on the screen exactly as it should be, so I'm thinking it's good.  I haven't began to get it working for each line yet, because it's not even working on the first line.

I get an invalid payload 400 when I run it.

EDIT:  Slack support said the what they were receiving has escape characters inserted into for some reason.

`"{\"text\": \"<https://alert-system.com/alerts/1234|Click here> for details!"}\n"`

Any direction or assistance is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I already had the data preformatted in the file as JSON already, it was just a matter of removing json.dumps out of the code.

**OLD:**

```
#response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

**NEW:**

```
response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=slack_data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Once I did that, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting as it might help somebody. For me the below snippet worked:

```
data = json.dumps(slack_data)
    response = requests.post(
        URL, json={"text": data},
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
```

As @Geo pointed out the final payload that we are going to send should have keyword ***"text"***, else it will fail.

Moreover, in post method I have to replace ***data=*** with ***json=*** else it kept throwing error for invalid payload with 400

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code to this:

```
with open('export.txt', 'r') as e:
    slack_data = e.read()
```

do you still get the 400?

Comment: I get "ValueError:  Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data" error

Comment: Hang on, I got that going in a with / for statement.. let me take that out and try it

Comment: still getting invalid_payload

Comment: are you sending `slack_data` as it is, or are you sending it as `slack_data = {"text": slack_data}` ? From your first example, I'm guessing it's expecting a dict.

Comment: Sorry just saw your comment.  It's supposed to be slack_data = {"text": "<https://alert-system.com/alerts/1234|Click here> for details!"}  That's how it is in the file and that's how I post it when I run it manually (and it works running it manually).

Comment: Slack support said the what they were receiving has escape characters inserted into for some reason.  "{\"text\": \"<https://alert-system.com/alerts/1234|Click here> for details!"}\n"